# Has anyone tried the DJ - Jquery webcontrols for ASP.Net?

Tags: jquery-ui, webforms

This suite provides a asp.net webcontrol abstraction over Jquery UI plugins. The team is working with asp.net webforms only and moving to asp.net mvc is not an option. We are looking to use jQuery to replace ajaxcontrol toolkit. DJ - jQuery for ASP.Net attempts to provide the same level of abstraction as ajaxcontrol toolkit to which Developers have got accustomed to. Has anyone used this? Any pros and cons information is appreciated.

[Site Link](http://dj.codeplex.com/releases/view/56780)

Comment: It might be helpful if you ask a question that's more specific than "What are your thoughts?"

Comment: pressed ask a bit early before phrasing the qn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial thoughts are that it is unnecessary to utilize wrappers around jQuery UI or any jQuery with ASP.NET Web Forms.  I have on numerous occasions been able to integrate both jQuery UI and other jQuery-based plugins without much trouble.  There are certainly rules that you need to follow to co-exist jQuery UI in a post-back world, but in general it is something easy to adapt to.  Wrappers like this tend to create a tremendous dependency on a third-party who is neither financially or often emotionally dedicated to supporting and maintaining the wrapper.  If you wish to have rich user functionality you would be better served long-term to fall back to commericial solutions like those from Telerik or Ingragistics.  Sure they cost money, but the amount you will spend trying to reinvent the wheel adds up over time.  Either go straight jQuery UI or use a commerical package.